# How to create a dynamic block in terraform resource using a boolean value

Tags: terraform

I am trying to create a dynamic block based on a variable (currently a bool). From my reading so far it seems the only options available to me are for_each and for (or a combination). I can't seem to use count as that is a resource level only function.

I believe for and foreach expect an iterable, so my best way should be to create one based on a for/if expression, although i'm not having much luck..

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Current code is:

```
dynamic "job_cluster" {
    for_each = [for cluster in ["true"] : [] if var.jobs[0].uses_existing_cluster]

    content {
      job_cluster_key = var.jobs[0].cluster.cluster_key
      new_cluster {
        #num_workers   = 2
        node_type_id  = data.databricks_node_type.smallest.id
    }
}
```

I don't get any error message with this approach, but it does not fire when the `bool=true`

Comment: Where is the `cluster` in `for cluster ...` coming from?

Comment: hmm - this was my guess at how to create a list with either 1 element or no elements in.

Comment: So the cluster has no value? It's just an iterator for the `for` loop that is always `true`? Is there another variable that you want to base the `dynamic` block on?

Comment: yes the dynamic block should be based on the var.jobs[0].uses_existing_cluster variable, which is a boolean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am guessing that the real question here is how to code a conditional for a dynamic block based on a `bool` type value assigned to `var.jobs[0].uses_existing_cluster`. In that situation we can simply use a ternary to return a dummy `list` (acceptable type in `for_each` for dynamic blocks although not resources for reasons of state) for a `true` logical return, and an empty `list` for a false return to short-circuit evaluate lazily:

```
dynamic "job_cluster" {
  for_each = var.jobs[0].uses_existing_cluster ? ["this"] : []

  content {
    job_cluster_key = var.jobs[0].cluster.cluster_key
      new_cluster {
        #num_workers = 2
        node_type_id = data.databricks_node_type.smallest.id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

where I also fixed a couple missing terminating brackets above also. I assumed that the enumerable is not necessary as it is not being used to assign values in your question. Also, if you need multiple iterations for the dynamic block, then the `range` function is commonly used:

```
dynamic "job_cluster" {
  # two iterations
  for_each = var.jobs[0].uses_existing_cluster ? range(1) : []

  content {
    job_cluster_key = var.jobs[0].cluster.cluster_key
      new_cluster {
        #num_workers = 2
        node_type_id = data.databricks_node_type.smallest.id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If the variable you have is only a simple bool value then it should be pretty simple:

```
dynamic "job_cluster" {
    for_each = var.jobs[0].uses_existing_cluster ?  [1] : []

    content {
      job_cluster_key = var.jobs[0].cluster.cluster_key
      new_cluster {
        node_type_id  = data.databricks_node_type.smallest.id
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your crystal ball is apparently similar to mine.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Great answer from you as well, with more detailed explanation. :)